# What is consistency under sampling? a more intuitive explanation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3054) the author's show that the Exponential random graphs do not admit consistency under sampling. The meaning of consistency under sampling is said to be equivalent to a condition called projectivity:

**Projectivity:**
A family of probability distribution $P_{\theta}(\mathbf{X})$ on $\mathbf{X} = \langle X_1 ...X_n\rangle$, which is defined for all $n$, is said to be projective if:

$$P_{\theta}(X_1...X_i) =  \sum_{\langle X_{i+1} ... X_n  \rangle}P_{\theta}(X_1...X_n)$$
for all possible values of $n$.

Projectivity is said to be a condition drawn from stochastic processes, I understand the condition, but what does it have to do with "consistency under sampling", what does consistency under sampling mean ?

Comment: Found a good explanation from the authors of the paper: http://bactra.org/notebooks/projectivity.html